# Where is the 'commanding officer'?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've just landed on the moon of Palaven (after first going to the Citadel) and I'm told to 'find commanding officer' but I can't find him/her/it. Where do I go?

[image: This is all I'm told]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The commanding officer of the Turian troops is up on your right, under one of the metal overhangs.  If you explore a bit in the camp, you'll find him quickly.  He's standing over a computer terminal, and there are other soldiers around him giving reports and taking orders.

[image: The view upon entering]

Answer (score 0):

The location is visible in the picture you provided...

[image]